# installing arc.js library in OpenLayers not working

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I have project developed in Angular 5 with Node.js . 
Now in my project I want to have flight animation connections and used the example of OpenLayers called 'Flight Animation'. The problem is that there is a library called 'arc.js' used in example which I could not import it. I installed the library using 'npm install --save arc' but still 'arc' is not recognized. My code is :

```
lineAnimation(){

var style = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#EAE911',
    width: 2
  })
});

var flightsSource;
var addLater = function (feature, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    feature.set('start', new Date().getTime());
    flightsSource.addFeature(feature);
  }, timeout);
};
var pointsPerMs = 0.1;
var animateFlights = function (event) {
  var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
  var frameState = event.frameState;
  vectorContext.setStyle(style);
  var features = flightsSource.getFeatures();
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    var feature = features[i];
    if (!feature.get('finished')) {
      // only draw the lines for which the animation has not finished yet
      var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      var elapsedTime = frameState.time - feature.get('start');
      var elapsedPoints = elapsedTime * pointsPerMs;

      if (elapsedPoints >= coords.length) {
        feature.set('finished', true);
      }
      var maxIndex = Math.min(elapsedPoints, coords.length);
      var currentLine = new LineString(coords.slice(0, maxIndex));

      // directly draw the line with the vector context
      vectorContext.drawGeometry(currentLine);
    }
  }
  // tell OpenLayers to continue the animation
  this.Map.render();
};
flightsSource = new SourceVector({
  wrapX: false,
  attributions: 'Flight data by ' +
    '<a href="http://openflights.org/data.html">OpenFlights</a>,',
  loader: function () {
    var url = 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/openflights/flights.json';
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
      var flightsData = json.flights;
      for (var i = 0; i < flightsData.length; i++) {
        var flight = flightsData[i];
        var from = flight[0];
        var to = flight[1];
        // create an arc circle between the two locations
        var arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle(
          { x: from[1], y: from[0] },
          { x: to[1], y: to[0] });

        var arcLine = arcGenerator.Arc(100, { offset: 10 });
        if (arcLine.geometries.length === 1) {
          var line = new LineString(arcLine.geometries[0].coords);
          line.transform(Proj.get('EPSG:4326'), Proj.get('EPSG:3857'));

          var feature = new Feature({
            geometry: line,
            finished: false
          });
          // add the feature with a delay so that the animation
          // for all features does not start at the same time
          addLater(feature, i * 50);
        }
      }
      this.Map.on('postcompose', animateFlights);
    });
  }
});
var flightsLayer = new LayerVector({
  source: flightsSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    // if the animation is still active for a feature, do not
    // render the feature with the layer style
    if (feature.get('finished')) {
      return style;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
});
this.map.addLayer(flightsLayer);
```

}

I get the error in 'var arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle('

Answer (score 1):

arc.js has been saved but not called on your map. The [documentation](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) says

```
Usage
Require the library in node.js like:

var arc = require('arc');
Use in the browser like:

<script src="./arc.js"></script>
```